# Can Google crawler see links in hidden navigation menu?

Tags: google

Hello I have a website that has a hamburger menu. The menu is closed by default but when clicked it will open and display links such as login, about etc. 
Can Googles crawler see these links even though they are hidden by default?

Comment: If it's in your HTML they can see it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the crawlers analyze the source code. Sign up to google webmaster tools and make sure that your site has no crawl errors.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot is not human.  It just sees HTML pages like a text file, so if the URL exists there, it will index it.

Comment: Google does visually render pages and does give priority to content immediately visible.